# latlng cannot be null - a position is required

Tags: react-native, maps, react-native-maps

I have a reactnative mobile application and use react-native-maps, I want to load markers at start of the application, but I am getting the `latlng cannot be null - a position is required` error.
What I am trying to do is fill the array markers

```
export default class MapScreen extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
            console.log(position.coords) // get your showUserLocation here
        },
        (error) => console.log(error.message), GEOLOCATION_SETTINGS
    )



    this.state = {
        region: {
            latitude: LATITUDE,
            longitude: LONGITUDE,
            latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
            longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
        },
        markers: [{
          title: 'FINISH',
          description: 'You have found me!',
          coordinates: {
           latitude: 14.548100,
           longitude: 121.049906
        }, 
       }]
    }
}
```

It is then called later:

```
                    {this.state.markers.map(marker => (
                    <Marker
                        key={marker.key}
                        coordinate={marker.coordinate}
                        pinColor={marker.color}
                    >
                        {/* Callout est l'infowindow */}
                        <Callout style={styles.plainView}>
                            <View>
                                {/* Texte par défaut pour le moment, à changer (voir ticket MARKER3) */}
                                <Text>
                                    Nom + Coordonnées + click here to see info
                                </Text>
                            </View>
                        </Callout>
                    </Marker>
                ))}
```

I am guessing that the way I give the information in `markers[]` is wrong, but I tried everything I could think of, including

```
        markers: [{
         latlng: {
           latitude: 14.548100,
           longitude: 121.049906
       }, 
   }]
```

and it still tells me latlng is null.
Is the problem really the input syntax? How can I find the correct one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo on your code at `coordinate={marker.coordinate}`, should be `coordinate={marker.coordinates}` like what you defined on your state.

```
    markers: [{
      title: 'FINISH',
      description: 'You have found me!',
      coordinates: {
       latitude: 14.548100,
       longitude: 121.049906
    }, 
   }]
```

Also you missed `key` and `color` on your state.

```
    markers: [{
      title: 'FINISH',
      description: 'You have found me!',
      coordinates: {
       latitude: 14.548100,
       longitude: 121.049906
      },
      key: 'YOUR_KEY_VALUE',
      color: 'YOUR_COLOR_VALUE' 
   }]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, I would have never noticed that typo